# VBA - Argument not optional error ! Trying to set the enabled property of a Listbox based on the Selected Value of another Listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form named as `NoForm` which has two List-boxes named as No_ListBox1 and No_ListBox4.

By Default, the Property of No_ListBox4 is set to be `enabled = false`

when No_ListBox1 value is "yes", , the Property of No_ListBox4 is set to be `enabled = true`

When it is "No", it stays as `enabled = false`. But here comes the Problem, I am not able to deselect the selected values in No_ListBox4 when the user changes it back to "No" in No_ListBox1.

Kindly Share your thoughts.

But,

This is the Code,

```
Private Sub No_ListBox1_Click()

SelectNext = NoForm.No_ListBox1.Value

If SelectNext = "Yes" Then

NoForm.No_ListBox4.Enabled = True

End If

If SelectNext = "No" Then

NoForm.No_ListBox4.Enabled = False

    If NoForm.No_ListBox4.Selected = True Then
        NoForm.No_ListBox4.Selected = False
    End If

End If
```

Comment: Your title does not really match the question you are asking.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Sorry mate ! feel free to edit it for the better :)

Comment: "Argument not optional" means you **MUST** specify an argument for a member call you're making. This is a compile-time error, so the VBE is highlighting the faulty/malformed statement. You can't get or assign `NoForm.No_ListBox4.Selected` without specifying an index in the list. Downvoted for not bothering to specify that kinda fundamental part of the problem. We can edit your post, sure. But it's your responsibility to properly desribe the problem. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the feedback. I will learn from these things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub No_ListBox1_Click()
    With Me
        If .No_ListBox1.Value = "Yes" Then
            .No_ListBox4.Enabled = True
        Else
            With .No_ListBox4
                .Selected(.ListIndex) = False
                .Enabled = False
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to flip your logic around.  Deselect the items first, then disable the control.